# Listing every one of the variables stored in JMeterVariables

Tags: jmeter

I'm making extensive use of JMeterVariables/vars in my current JMeter code- in particular I'm generating variable names dynamically, based on JSON input.

Is there any way of getting the program to kick out a list of every single variable that is stored in `vars`??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following:

- Add [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) in your script, with `JMeter Variables = true`
- Similarly, add [Debug Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_PostProcessor) under the sampler which creates dynamic variables
- Since `vars` is just a regular `Map`, you can iterate it using one of the scripting languages (BeanShll, Groovy, etc):

  ```
  for(java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object> var in vars.entrySet())
  {
      log.info(var.getKey() + "=" + var.getValue().toString());
  }
  ```

Note that some variables are objects, so their representation will depend on how `toString()` function is implemented for them.

Comment: Yep, that's covered it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your Test Plan
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.entrySet().each { var ->
      log.info(var.getKey() + '=' + var.getValue())
   }
   ```
3. All the variable names and values will be printed to *jmeter.log* file

   [image: JMeter Variables print to log]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)